# java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle

I am face with a problem this day. I have tried to make a shakeout with my database, which is Oracle 11g installed localy on my pc and using  JAR Ojdbc6, to connect on it using few line of java code. But anything what I have tried wasn't worked.
Tried :
- Connection with SQL DEV =>is worked
- Start  Listener => All ready started
- Try to change the Ip from the URL => still can't connect
I see that is a generic error, but no one has a good response. I can't understand why with SQL DEV is working but with Eclipse not.

I Hope that someone can' help me,

This is my code :

```
package testare;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class oracle {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");

        try {

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

        Connection connection = null;

        try {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl", "hr","hr");
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    }

}
```

This is my Error:

```
-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------
Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!
Connection Failed! Check output console
java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:480)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:413)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:508)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:203)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:33)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:510)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at testare.oracle.main(oracle.java:31)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:328)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:421)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:630)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:329)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:966)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:292)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:127)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:126)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:306)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the correct URL would be `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl`